# How to get the coordinates of a click event inside Panel? 

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, c++-cli

How can one get the coordinates of a mouse click inside a panel?
For instance I want to be able to put pixels wherever I click with my mouse. I can handle the drawing part, but I don't know how to make my program to listen for that click event, and how to get x/y coordinates of it so it can draw in right place.

I never saw a similar piece of code, and I was unable to find relevant information with google so I can't show any code "how I tried to achieve that" because I simply didn't :/ I have no clue how to start. I am probably searching the wrong keywords, but I am sure that it can be done.

EDIT: Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/258894) is a complete hint for your question, with code. For the panel you can use the `mouseDown` event. And from the event arguments you can get the coords.

Answer (score 4):

The Click event is not the right choice.  It can be generated both by the mouse and the keyboard so it doesn't pass the mouse position.  A button for example can be clicked by pressing the space bar.  This of course won't happen for a panel.  Simply use the MouseUp event instead.  Check the passed e->Button property.

A panel is not the good choice either btw.  It is not double-buffered so it is likely to start flickering when the drawing gets intricate.  It doesn't redraw properly when the size changes.  A PictureBox doesn't have these problems.  Just treat it like the panel, implement its Paint event and don't set the Image property.

Answer (score 1):

```
private: System::Void panel1_MouseDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::MouseEventArgs^  e) 
{    
     int x= e->X;
     int y= e->y;
}
```